# UIPanGestureRecognizer : Handling UIPanGestureRecognizer in a view

Tags: uiview, pull, uipangesturerecognizer

I have a UIView. I need to move that view like "pullable view like Notification Center of iPhone" top to bottom and bottom to top. How can i do this ? Is it possible by using UIPanGestureRecognizer?

Comment: Hi, I hate to bring up an old post, but I'm trying to do exactly the same thing you are doing. Have you figured it out and if so, can you point me in the direction to achieve the same with UIPanGestureRecognizer? thanks